# Strange behaviour of expression index

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table:

```sql
create table test_coordinates(
    coordinates geometry,
    radius integer not null default random() * 20000 + 1000
);
```

It's a set points with radiuses – essentially, circles.

I want to see, which circles a given point lies in, on Earth's surface. I want to use index for this, so I query the next way:

```sql
select * from test_coordinates
where st_covers(st_buffer(
   coordinates::geography,
   radius, 
   st_makepoint(59.91033806688409, 10.74357882142067));
```

And index the table this way:

```sql
create index "polygon_index" on test_coordinates
using gist(st_buffer(
    coordinates::geography,
    radius));
```

As `analyze explain` shows, the query uses the index. So far so good. But knowing that `st_buffer` makes an inscribed polygon, so this cuts off some results, I want to expand my buffer a bit by adding a 5% of radius to it. Now, the index and the query will look this way:

```sql
create index "polygon_index" on test_coordinates
    using gist(st_buffer(
        coordinates::geography,
        radius + radius / 20));
explain analyse select * from test_coordinates
    where st_covers(st_buffer(
        coordinates::geography,
        radius + radius / 20), -- note: don't mind that it's not precise; in reality it's followed by st_dwithin
    st_makepoint(59.91033806688409, 10.74357882142067));
```

Surprisingly, the index now is not being used. Adding that `+ radius / 20` prevents its usage somehow. Why this happens?

The only way of solving that impossibility to add something to radius I found is altering the coordinates column type itself:

```sql
alter table test_coordinates alter column coordinates type geography;
```

Then, if I remove all casts to `geography` from above, adding `+ radius / 20` both to index and query doesn't prevent index usage. Why altering column type works, but simple casts in queries and index don't? Is this a bug? Is there a way of accomplishing this without altering column type?

Comment: Have a look at [`st_dwithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) to find points within a given distance from another one. You can then directly index the geometry/geography

Comment: @JGH I forgot to note that I actually do use st_dwithin along with this indexed search. Edited the question. Sole st_dwithin will do only sequential scan, because you still have to calculate distance for each and every row in the table. That's why I setup fast and dirty index usage to throw away all those which obviously don't fit the query, and then filter the result by st_dwithin to be precise.

Comment: it is supposed to do a bounding box comparison using the spatial index.

Comment: @JGH it is, unless you try to use it the other way around. I don't have a single point, around which I want to use st_dwithin. Instead, I have a table of points and radiuses, for each of which I want to use st_dwithin with a given point. In this case, index can't be used.